# Building a Contact Database - Need a little schema inspiration

Tags: database-design, street-address

I've been working on laying out the data structure for an application I'm working on.  One of the things it will need to handle is storing customer / contact information.  I've been studying the interface of a few different contact information programs like Address Book, gmail contacts, etc.

I have basically boiled the contact down to an "entity" (individual, company, role, etc).

- Each **Entity** can have multiple **Address**, **Phone**, **E-Mail** entries.

  - Each of these defines a "relationship" (home/work/assistant, etc)
  - **Entity** {1} --{relationship}--> {0..*} **Data**
- An **Entity** can have multiple **fields** that are freeform data storage for other "generic" data (birthdays, AIM account, etc)

  - **Entity** {1} --{fieldName}--> {0..*} **Field Data**
- An **Entity** can link to another **Entity** for instance as a *employee*, *spouse*

  - **Entity** {0..*} <--{relationship}--> {0..*} **Entity**

Has anyone done any SQL implementations of similar contact databases?  Any insight/suggestions/pitfalls to avoid that you could share with someone trying to work on a project by themselves here?  Does what I have described seem reasonable or overcomplicated?

One question, lets say you have 4 people who all work for the same company.  They all have the same "work" phone number (perhaps with a different extension) - If the number or address for "work" changes, I'd like to be able to update the contacts fairly easily.  Now a lot of this comes down to how you would use the database.  I'm thinking that this becomes a matter of linking employee's to their respective company entities, but then the address/phone number is no longer directly connected to the employee.  I'm kind of debating making the Entity/data relationship many to many allowing you to attach the same mailing address/phone number to multiple people, and updating it in one place can update it in all places.  Am I just over thinking this? *pulls out hair*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a bit trite, but you need to know your data and what you're going to do with it before you start thinking tables.

I'd suggest looking at [Object Role Modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Role_Modeling) (or [this](http://www.orm.net/) too) to define the model in plain English before you actually implement any tables. I use this VS plugin: [NORMA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orm/) that will also generate a schema for you too.

Alternatively, there are a bunch of [data models here](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/) that may inspire you.
This is "Contact Management" but there are others, such as the "Customers" section

(I just wanted to post an image..)
[image: Contact Management]
<sub>(source: [databaseanswers.org](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/contact_management/images/contact_management_model.gif))</sub>

Comment: Great resource follow up with the link

Comment: Thanks for the links, definitely some helpful ones there.  The layout in that image seems very much like what I started thinking about with the many/many relationship `Customer_Addresses`... I also am thinking that this might over complicate the maintenance of updating/entering information.  I.E. How do you select the "same address" as another contact vs. duplicating the address in the table.

Comment: @gnarf: I haven't used or analyzed this model, sorry. I just know the site

Comment: no problem, still inspirational... just putting my thoughts out in the open :)

Comment: http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/ is a "Reported Attack Page" by Google :(

Answer (score 4):

This is just to help with your second question; where phone extension actually belongs to relationship between person and company entities.

[image: contact_model_01]

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense for extensions to be a part of the "relationship" between a person and a phone #.

Comment: Out of curiosity - Where did that image come from?

Comment: What if a company has multiple branches/locations/addresses?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft offers a number of starter databases schemas, including Assets Maintenance, Contact Management, Customers and Orders, Document Management, e-Commerce, Help Desk, Issue Tracking Software, Retail Inventory Control, and Product Catalogs. See [Starter Database Schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/express/bb403186).

---

***EDIT*** (April 2016): It appear the Microsoft webmaster broke the link. Here's the [Wayback Machine archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20120419144612/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/express/bb403186) of the page.

Comment: @Henry. It looks like the Microsoft Webmaster broke the link. You should probably contact Microsoft at ssedmf@microsoft.com, and ask them to fix it. The email address was provided at the Starter Database page as a point of contact. But I would not be surprised if the Microsoft Postmaster broke that email address, too.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points that tend to crop up in my experience..

Consider reciprocal relationships. For example, if someone is defined as being an employee of a company, then the company is then by definition the employer of that person.

Are you considering addresses as entities in themselves, or as merely free text associated with a person/place? In some applications, the address (physical building etc) is 'real' and only one can exist in the table. (Often using the government/postal identifier for it).

Comment: Yeah - Reciprocal relationships were already in the works, I was figuring you could define **A** is an *employee of* **B** and therefore, **B** has *employee* **A** as well.  - Yes, addresses are intentionally going to be their own table, I'm trying to lower the chances of having duplicate address information in the table by making it potentially a many to many relationship.  Same with phone numbers.. I'd like to know if bob has the same # as joe...